# Screw Modifier On Top of Shape Key

Tags: modeling, modifiers, screw-modifier

[image: screw modifier]

I was trying out the [shape key addon](https://youtu.be/o6oCFZsM87M) using [this demo SVG](https://github.com/Shriinivas/shapekeyimport/blob/master/morphing%20of%20chess%20pieces.svg). The morphing works fine, but when I apply the screw modifier the normals look reversed for both the shapes. How can this be fixed?

Comment: Have you tried the 'Flip' checkbox in the Screw modifier?

Comment: It looks like it's the problem, I think you can put it as an answer

Comment: @RobinBetts Yes, that was it. Thank you! If you could just put it in the answer, I would mark the question as answered. I have another related question. Will create a separate topic for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to set the 'Flip' checkbox in the Screw Modifier. ;)

Comment: Or, come to think of it, put a '-' in front of the Angle...

Comment: :) Yep! And apparently, Blender follows the right hand thumb rule here also, just as in case of setting normals to the faces. So another way of achieving this is to reverse the curves in the source SVG.